# Perform different action on button name jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm performing insert and update through same function but base on button name, like this

```
var currentButtonName = $jqueryLib(this).val();   
if(currentButtonName == "Add"){}
else if(currentButtonName == "Update"){}
```

I am changing the button name from other function. The question i want to ask, is this correct approach to do this? or it pose any risk?

Comment: Aren't you have two buttons?If yes based on `id` perform click event and directly go for addition and updation as both button will share different `id` like `<button id="add">Add</button><button id="update>Update</button>"`. If you have these buttons inside any loop (mutiple records) the use `class` instead of `id` like ``<button class="add">Add</button><button class="update>Update</button>"``

Comment: Which kind of risk are you referring here? If for security reason, this has to be handled server side anyway

Comment: You mean normal Button tag?

Comment: If you are asking about the right method then I would say that you should separate these two functions as you might have read that functions should do one thing. This helps in achieving modular code which are loosely coupled with each other for better coding

Answer (score 0):

Sniffing the button's `value` is definitely not a good way to do this. What happens if you translate your site to another language? The values won't be "Add" or "Update" any more.

And as orangespark pointed out, if these buttons do two different things, they should have two different functions.

So assign each button an `id` or `class` and give each one its own event handler, perhaps like this:

```js
$('#add').click( function() {
    console.log( this.value );
});

$('#update').click( function() {
    console.log( this.value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Añadir">
<input type="button" id="update" value="Actualizar">
```